# Spring not using test configuration bean for tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class with dependency Spring Batch JobLauncher.

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    JobExplorer jobExplorer;

   //...

}
```

I want to use ASynchronous version of this JobLauncher, so I create a config:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "asyncJobLauncher")
    @Primary
    public JobLauncher asyncJobLauncher(final JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }
}
```

I am forced to used `@Primary`, otherwise some other Synchronous JobLauncher gets picked up when application is running.

Now, In my test, I want to use Synchronous version as I validate the results of the job executions. Therefore I define the Synchronous  bean in Configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes= {RepoTests.TestConfig.class, MyApp.class},
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@ActiveProfiles("h2,test")
public class ControllerTest extends AbstractRestController {

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Configuration {

        @Autowired
        JobRepository jobRepository;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public JobLauncher jobLauncher() {
            SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
            jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);;
            return jobLauncher;
        }

    } 
   //..tests
}
```

However, when my test runs..it always uses the async version and my results are not correct.

Is there a way I can use the Synchronous jobLauncher in my test?

Comment: Can you try @Import as described here: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/test-configuration.html

Comment: Even with @Import it was using the main one.

Comment: It seems that your test config is ignored. Can you somehow verify that jobLauncher bean method is invoked at all?

Comment: That one gets invoked. I tested this. But when controller code runs, uses main beam

Comment: Please see my answer below. BR

Comment: Any luck with the last mod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to annotate app bean with `@Profile("!test")`

```
@Profile("!test")
@Bean(name = "asyncJobLauncher")
@Primary
public JobLauncher asyncJobLauncher(final JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception 
{
  ...
```

Comment: I had hoped for a solution that didn't require an additional line or using @Profile in the main Batch Config, but this works I guess for now :). Thank you